# Keep queues and exchanges when vhost is corrupted

Tags: rabbitmq, vhosts

We've recently come across a problem when using RabbitMQ: when the hard drive of our server is full, RabbitMQ's vhost are getting corrupted, and unusable.

The only to make RabbitMQ functional again is to delete, and recreate the corrupted hosts.

Doing so, all of our queues, and exchanges, along with the data in it, is then gone.

While this situation should not happen in prod, we're searching for a way to prevent data loss, if such an event does occur.

We've been looking at the official rabbitMQ documentation, as well as on stack exchange, but haven't found any solution to prevent data loss when a host is corrupted.

We plan on setting up a cluster at a later stage of development, which should at least help in reducing the loss of data when a vhost is corrupted, but it's not possible for now.

Is there any reliable way to either prevent vhost corruption, or to fix the vhost without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on this (in no particular order):

1. RabbitMQ has multiple [high-availability configurations](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) - relying upon a single node provides no protection against data loss.
2. In general, you can have one of two possible guarantees with a message, but never both:

   - At least once delivery - a message will be delivered at least one time, and possibly more.
   - At most once delivery - a message may or may not be delivered, but if it is delivered, it will never be delivered a second time
3. Monitoring the overall health of your nodes (i.e. disk space, processor use, memory, etc.) should be done proactively by a tool specific to that purpose. You should never be surprised by running out of a critical system resource.
4. If you are running one node, and that node is out of disk space, and you have a bunch of messages on it, and you're worried about data loss, wondering how RabbitMQ can help you, I would say you have your priorities mixed up.
5. RabbitMQ is not a database. It is not designed to reliably store messages for an indefinite time period. Please don't count on it as such.